# How can I play and convert (old) autodesk animator files (FLI files) to MP4 in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

How can I play and convert (old) autodesk animator files (FLI files) in Windows 7?

An example FLI file.

```
http://www.sendspace.com/file/sxp6yh
or
http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gd7e8082953117caa999275411c6cb8b07ea43b8b7
or
http://tinyurl.com/d7hnhcm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fli is actually much more like an animated gif, than an mp4. 
And, it turns out that The GIMP does a great job of converting FLI to GIF.

[image: gif version]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert them to a GIF file, use ffmpeg together with image magick’s convert.

Or just use ffmpeg to convert it to any other video format.

This is how to convert from FLI to GIF as a script:

```
FILE="oldfile.fli"

# get frames per second of original file
FPS=$(ffmpeg -i "$FILE" 2>&1| sed -n '/tbr/s%.*\ \([0-9\.]\+\)\ tbr.*%\1%p')

# get delay for image magick animated-gif-creation in hundredths of second
DELAY100=$(awk 'BEGIN {print '100/$FPS'}')

# extract video to PNG images
ffmpeg -i "$FILE" "${FILE%.*}"%05d.png

# create gif file
convert -delay $DELAY100 ${FILE%.*}"?????.png -loop 0 output.gif

# optionally optimize the GIF file with gifsicle
gifsicle --colors 256 -O3 output.gif -o better_output.gif
```